# ¿como puedo subir archivos pesados de php a a mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Lo que pasa es que intento subir archivos pesados a mysql, pero al parecer no me deja sino hasta los 6MB (Obvio, para el trabajo que hago, estos archivos después se eliminan) y ya busqué, hasta intenté con algo que se llama buffe, pero tampoco. Les muestro el código:

```html
<input type="text" name='txtnom' id="txtnom">
      
      <input type="file" name='foto[]' id='foto' multiple>

       <button>Subir fotos</button>

    </form>
    
    
    
    <?php
    
      $foto= $_FILES['foto'];

      for($i=0;$i<count($foto['tmp_name']);$i++){
        

        $fopenFile=fopen($foto['tmp_name'][$i], 'r'); //Tiene que ver algo del permiso?
        $freadFile=fread($fopenFile, filesize($foto['tmp_name'][$i]));
        fclose($fopenFile);

        $this->modelo->insertImage(['foto_subir' => $freadFile]);

      }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Revisa tal vez necesites modificar el [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Comment: ya lo miré, pero tenía hasta 40 megas

Comment: Te dejo un enlace donde explican algo al respecto,  es solo referencia, al final la construccion de el sistema y de la BD depende de los requerimientos y necesidades propias del desarrollo o de la empresa.  Yo en lo personal apuesto mas por crear un repositorio y almacenar ahi los archivos, y en la base de datos puedes hacer un tabla donde guardes la referencia de donde se almacena, la extension, el tamaño y algunas cosas mas que se te puedan ocurrir.

Comment: de hecho, ya lo configuré en php.ini, además de colocar ON en display_errors (para ver los errores) y nada

Answer (score 0):

Chicos, ya resolví el problema. Si al configurar en php.ini y le aumentan a más de 2M y no les da, entonces vayan a my.ini (la encuentran en mysql/bin/my.ini o se van a XAMPP, dan click en config y click en my.ini) ya ahí buscan: max_allowed_packet y lo cambian dependiendo de cuantas megas quieren, en mi caso le pongo 10M. No olviden guardarlo y reiniciar el XAMPP